# ¿Cómo solucionar comportamiento extraño en el 'refresh' de botones con PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica, layout

Siempre que comienzo a estudiar la interface gráfica de un nuevo lenguaje hago el rompecabezas deslizable conocido como "Juego de los 15" ([Ver la explicación de lo que es aquí](https://www.psicoactiva.com/juegos-inteligencia/fifteen/).

[image: Imagen del Juego de los 15]

Es un excelente ejercicio para la enseñanza y el aprendizaje. Lo he hecho en Java, en VB6 y NET, etc. Por el ascenso de Python me he puesto a estudiarlo y he hecho un pequeño código importando PySimpleGUI y el programa funciona únicamente en la columna de la derecha (es decir si hago clic en el 12, luego en el 8, luego en el 4); cuando se trata de involucrar un botón de otra columna (por ejemplo el 15), no funciona. No me considero un desarrollador novato, pero este error ha resistido desde hace una semana mis esfuerzos de depuración. Como lo estoy haciendo para mi aprendizaje de los fundamentos de PySimpleGUI y como práctica de Python, lo he estado trabajando sin prisa y con paciencia.  El código, con comentarios y todo es de 44 líneas (lo pondré al final). Lo que trajo mi desconcierto es que al mantener visible el botón que simula el hueco (al cambiar el *False* por *True* en la línea 27) y como dicho botón no tiene etiqueta se distingue claramente de los demás, entonces el juego funciona perfectamente. Esto me hace sospechar que estoy pasando por alto algo que tiene que ver con el manejo del *layout* de PySimpleGUI. He probado agregando un *ventana.Refresh()* al final de la función (aun cuando me parece ilógico por que con unos botones sí se "refrescan" los cambios de la ventana) sin que nada mejore.
Por supuesto, para que funcione el código se debe instalar PySimpleGUI (pip install PySimpleGUI). Mi gratitud profunda a quienes me lean, en especial a quienes, además me ayuden.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
#Declara varaibles globales y constantes
elInvisible=15 #Variable que informa el índice del botón que está invisible
botones=list() #La colección de botones que son el juego
VECINOS=[[1,4],[0,2,5],[1,3,6],[2,7], #Establece, asociado al índice de VECINOS, cuáles son los botones vecios del mismo
        [0,5,8],[1,4,6,9],[2,5,7,10],[3,6,11],
        [4,9,12],[5,8,10,13],[6,9,11,14],[7,10,15],
        [8,13],[9,12,14],[10,13,15],[11,14]] 
#Función que determina si un vecino es invisible y, si sí, realiza el cambio        
def esAlgunVecinoInvisible(indice):
    global elInvisible
    global VECINOS
    if elInvisible in VECINOS[indice]:
        for buscado in VECINOS[indice]:
            if buscado==elInvisible:
                botones[elInvisible].update(text=botones[indice].get_text(), visible=True)
                botones[indice].update(text="",visible=False)
                global ventana
                ventana.refresh()
                elInvisible=indice
                break                
#Bucle que inicializa los botones
for indice in range(16):
    if indice<15:#Los primeros 15 botones visibles 
        botones.append(sg.Button(indice+1,key=indice, size=(4,2)))
    else:#El botón que simula el hueco (invisible)
        botones.append(sg.Button(key=indice, size=(4,2), visible=False))
#La interface gráfica de usuario
layout = [ 
            [botones[0],botones[1],botones[2],botones[3]],
            [botones[4],botones[5],botones[6],botones[7]],
            [botones[8],botones[9],botones[10],botones[11]],
            [botones[12],botones[13],botones[14],botones[15]]
         ]
ventana = sg.Window('Juego 15', layout)
while True:             # Bucle de evebntos
    event, values = ventana.Read()    
    if event != None: #Cualquier clic en los botones
        indice=int(event)
        esAlgunVecinoInvisible(indice)
    else: #Los mecanismos de cierre de la ventana
        break
ventana.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En [la referencia de PySimpleGui](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/) en el apartado *Layout helper funcs* dice que cuando los componentes van a cambiar de invisible a visible en tiempo de ejecución se debe usar la función `pin()` para controlar su comportamiento (pasa que por defecto un control invisible ocupa sólo un pixel, para evitarlo el atributo *shrink* de `pin()` debe ser *False*). Por lo que el código de inicialización del *layout* quedó así:

```
layout = [ 
        [sg.pin(botones[0],shrink =False),sg.pin(botones[1],shrink =False),sg.pin(botones[2],shrink =False),sg.pin(botones[3],shrink =False)],
        [sg.pin(botones[4],shrink =False),sg.pin(botones[5],shrink =False),sg.pin(botones[6],shrink =False),sg.pin(botones[7],shrink =False)],
        [sg.pin(botones[8],shrink =False),sg.pin(botones[9],shrink =False),sg.pin(botones[10],shrink =False),sg.pin(botones[11],shrink =False)],
        [sg.pin(botones[12],shrink =False),sg.pin(botones[13],shrink =False),sg.pin(botones[14],shrink =False),sg.pin(botones[15],shrink =False)]
     ]
```